# constant similar "VM_RESERVED" and nopage method in 3.9.6

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Cannot find `VM_RESERVED` constant and `nopage` method(in `vm_operations_struct`) in 3.9.6. What is their replacement in 3.9.6 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In [the patch removing `VM_RESERVED`](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel.mm/83212/), the author had this advice:

> A long time ago, in v2.4, `VM_RESERVED` kept swapout process off VMA,
>   currently it lost original meaning but still has some effects:
>
> ```
>  | effect                 | alternative flags
> -+------------------------+---------------------------------------------
> 1| account as reserved_vm | VM_IO
> 2| skip in core dump      | VM_IO, VM_DONTDUMP
> 3| do not merge or expand | VM_IO, VM_DONTEXPAND, VM_HUGETLB, VM_PFNMAP
> 4| do not mlock           | VM_IO, VM_DONTEXPAND, VM_HUGETLB, VM_PFNMAP
> ```
>
> Thus `VM_RESERVED` can be replaced with `VM_IO` or pair `VM_DONTEXPAND |
>   VM_DONTDUMP`.

`vm_ops->nopage` was replaced with `vm_ops->fault` in [this patch](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/495930/).